# Spyder installation failed

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, spyder

i had spyder 4.2.0 installed but then i upgraded to spyder 4.2.1
but the installation failed...
and with that my "spyder 4.2.0" got uninstalled

i again tried installing it with pip...
(i know how to use pip so i use it)

with this command:

```
pip install --upgrade spyder --force-reinstall
```

but it gave me this error:

```
Collecting pyqt5<5.13
  Downloading PyQt5-5.12.3-5.12.10-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-none-win32.whl (43.5 MB)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 321, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 339, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name, criterion)
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 207, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_criteria_to_update(candidate)
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 198, in _get_criteria_to_update
    for r in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate):
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\provider.py", line 172, in get_dependencies
    for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires)
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\provider.py", line 171, in <listcomp>
    r
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 257, in iter_dependencies
    requires = self.dist.requires() if with_requires else ()
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 239, in dist
    self._prepare()
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 319, in _prepare_distribution
    self._ireq, parallel_builds=True,
  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 480, in prepare_linked_requirement
     |██▌                             | 3.3 MB 136 kB/s eta 0:04:55  File "c:\program files\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 480, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
```

but i have pyqt5 5.12.3 installed..

so what should i do!?

---

I found the answer:

```
pip install spyder==4.2.0
pip install pyqt5==5.10
```

everything worked!!!

Comment: Okay okay i found what i can do...   I installed pyqt5-5.10! it fixed everything